# Can I generate schema migrations from South that work on different databases [sqlite and postgresql]?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-south

I use sqlite3 on my dev server and when I change the schema, I'd like to be able to generate migrations on development that I can use on production, which uses postgresql. One option would be to generate the migrations directly on production and then apply them - I would ideally like to generate the migrations on development, and then upload the files to production and run the schema migration.

Comment: This may also be of interest to you: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andrewgodwin/schema-migrations-for-django

Comment: That's an awesome project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database independence is one of the [key features of South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html#key-features) - so you can generate the migrations wherever you like, and be confident that you'll be fine running them wherever you need to (even if you're using a different database than the one you used to generate the migration).

Comment: Thanks.. I should have skimmed that myself first, much appreciated.

Comment: @zallarak Read this part as well: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/databaseapi.html#database-specific-issues